# Qt::CustomizeWindowHint and Qt::Tool analogs for gtkmm

Tags: c++, qt, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I try to find `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` and `Qt::Tool` analogs for Gtkmm 3.0.

I want to design a simple program without system buttons like close, fullscreen mode etc.
In the official documentation I couldn't find it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`window->set_decorated(false)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Window.html#a67adb1d8051a38e0e5272f141bb8778c), although it is only a hint to the window manager. Some window managers don't support windows without system buttons.